# ZSH Couldn't Auto Complete Suggestion

Tags: zsh, fedora, oh-my-zsh

I'm running the latest Fedora with GNOME version 43.2.  I've installed ZSH and oh-my-zsh on my system.  When I tried to type "sudo dnf remove auda" and hit the tab button for autocompletion, I received the following suggestion from ZSH.  In other word, hitting TAB after auda will append the zsh: sqlite3 as you see below.

```
# Attempting to remove audacious
sudo dnf remove audazsh: sqlite3: command not found...
Install pacsudo dnf remove auda

# Another example trying to remove Gimp
sudo dnf remove gizsh: sqlite3: command not found...
Install pacsudo dnf remove gi
```

It seems any command ZSH and oh-my-zsh with auto-suggestion plugin will work just fine but not the application name itself.

Anyone run into this issue?  It's quite annoying.  I'd rather it not suggest anything instead of appending gibberish to the command.

Comment: For me installing `sqlite` actually helped.. https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?328382-Tab-completion-of-dnf-presents-error&p=1858668

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: As @vnj suggested, installed sqlite3 worked.